# How to compare arraylist with Hasmap and get the key from Hashmap based on value?

Tags: java, arraylist

I've got list :

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

and map :

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

I need to compare values of the list and map and return key based on that value

The problem is that I dont know how to synchronize iterations as arraylist has smaller size as each list in map.

Also I tried this method :

```
public static Object getKeyByValue(Map<String,List<String>> map, String value) {
    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (Objects.equals(value, entry.getValue())) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

getKeyByValue(map,list.get(0));
```

..but this call retuned false even If there is certain value...

Any ideas how get each key for each value? 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a `List<String>` to a `String`, so it would never return true.

Use `List.contains` instead, to determine if the `String` appears in the `List` :

```
    if (entry.getValue().contains(value)) {
        return entry.getKey();
    }
```